# CSS Grid - Why is my text being cut off when I resize to smaller screens?

Tags: css, css-grid

Like the title says, it is only the text at the far right off the screen that is cut off, when I inspect and view smaller device sizes.

Here is my HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 3fr;
  border: 2px solid #6cccb0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #6cccb0;
  width: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">

  <div>
    <p class="item1">SHIPPED for free | GUARANTEED TO LAST</p>
  </div>


  <div>
    <p class="item2">LOG IN | REGISTER | CUSTOMER SERVICE | 1-800-692-8259 </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try removing overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: or even better, remove  `width: 1700px;`

Comment: That doesn't work, and i'm trying to avoid a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Your grid is always 1700px width and the body overflow is hidden. If you want the text to wrap on a second line use something like `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: I'm trying to keep text on the same line

Comment: "Keeping lines on the same line" and "Not cut off on smaller screen" is contradictory. At some point, on smaller screen, text will have to be on multiple lines so that all letters can be shown. basically, you want the text on the left to be justified on the left, and that on the right to be justified to the right?

Comment: So, is text going to the next line unavoidable on smaller screens? Would it solve it if I made it an unordered list? Basically I want the text on the left justified left and the right to the right, and I think there's room.

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the hard-set width and the `overflow: hidden` properties? These are causing your content to be both *offscreen* and also cut.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #6cccb0;
  background-color: #6cccb0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">

  <div>
    <p class="item1">SHIPPED for free | GUARANTEED TO LAST</p>
  </div>


  <div>
    <p class="item2">LOG IN | REGISTER | CUSTOMER SERVICE | 1-800-692-8259 </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're right, that solved the cut off issue. But now what if I want the text on the same line, instead of being pushed to a new line on smaller screen resize?

Comment: Alright, first let's think about that, if the screen size is reduced, what should happen to the text? If you need to keep *all* the text visible *and* on the same line, then you should reduce the font-size enought so it looks good; because the only other option is to clip the text, but that would leave information out

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
width: 100%;
```

instead of

```
width: 1700px;
```

So your item2 text will not disappear.

Edit 1:

In case you want to keep your text in one line, I suggest using @media queries to change your font-size. so your css must be something like this.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
    border: 2px solid #6cccb0;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #6cccb0;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    .wrapper1 {
        font-size: 0.4em;
        color: yellow;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 440px) {
    .wrapper1 {
        font-size: 0.5em;
        color: aqua;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
    .wrapper1 {
        font-size: 0.6em;
        color: green;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
    .wrapper1 {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        color: blue;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .wrapper1 {
        font-size: 1em;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

I put color rules to help you understand what's happening. You can delete them. I hope it would help you.

Comment: When I do that the width of my div shrinks to half the screen on resize to smaller screens.

Comment: @Daniel Klein. I edited my answer so it could solve your problem I hope